# C++ Improve memory-map obj file

Tags: c++, performance, parsing, memory, dictionary

So once again I have met an obstacle I can't pass!
I'm trying to parse , load an obj file for OpenGL!

I have succeeded but it is very slow ( used ifstream )
So I'm now memory-mapping the file and parsing from there ( loads into memory very fast! ).

The problem is I can't figure out how to keep the speed even when parsing it!

Current Code:

```
HANDLE file = CreateFile((LPCSTR)loc.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if(file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { /* Error handling code! */ }
HANDLE file2 = CreateFileMapping(file, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, NULL, NULL, (LPCSTR)"CurrentParsingOBJ");
VOID* mappedData = MapViewOfFile(file2, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, NULL);
const char* data = new(mappedData) char[];

int i = 0;
bool v = false, vn = false, vt = false;
while(*(data + i) != '\0')
{
    if(*(data + i) == '\n') { v = false; vn = false; vt = false; ++i; continue; }
    if((*(data + i) == 'v' && *(data + i + 1) == ' ') || v)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int p = 0;
        int pp = 0;
        v = true;

    }
    ++i;
}
//Free Mapped Data!
if(UnmapViewOfFile(mappedData) == NULL) { /* Error handling code! */ }
mappedData = NULL;
data = NULL;
```

So far this is very good speed!
But I can't figure out how to parse it and maintain the speed!
I have tried many solutions but all of them led to unacceptable speed!

This is how I do it with ifstream ( I would like to load the same OBJData structure as here in the memory-mapped version aswell! ):

```
std::ifstream stream(loc);
if(stream.is_open())
{
    for(std::string line; std::getline(stream, line);)
    {
        if( StringUtil::StringStartsWith(line, "v " ) )
        {
            Vector3f vec = Vector3f((float)atof((StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[1])->c_str()), (float)atof((StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[2])->c_str()), (float)atof((StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[3])->c_str()));
            d->V.push_back(vec);
        }else if( StringUtil::StringStartsWith(line, "vn " ) )
        {
            Vector3f vec = Vector3f((float)atof((StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[1])->c_str()), (float)atof((StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[2])->c_str()), (float)atof((StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[3])->c_str()));
            d->VN.push_back(vec);
        }else if( StringUtil::StringStartsWith(line, "vt ") )
        {
            Vector3f vec = Vector3f((float)atof((StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[1])->c_str()), (float)atof((StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[2])->c_str()), 0.0F);
            d->VT.push_back(vec);
        }else if( StringUtil::StringStartsWith(line, "f ") )
        {
            Vector3f vert = Vector3f( (float)atof(StringUtil::Split( StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[1]->c_str(), '/' )[0]->c_str()),  (float)atof(StringUtil::Split( StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[2]->c_str(), '/' )[0]->c_str()),  (float)atof(StringUtil::Split( StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[3]->c_str(), '/' )[0]->c_str()) );
            Vector3f norms = Vector3f( (float)atof(StringUtil::Split( StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[1]->c_str(), '/' )[2]->c_str()),  (float)atof(StringUtil::Split( StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[2]->c_str(), '/' )[2]->c_str()),  (float)atof(StringUtil::Split( StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[3]->c_str(), '/' )[2]->c_str()) );
            Vector3f textures = Vector3f( (float)atof(StringUtil::Split( StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[1]->c_str(), '/' )[1]->c_str()),   (float)atof(StringUtil::Split( StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[2]->c_str(), '/' )[1]->c_str()),   (float)atof(StringUtil::Split( StringUtil::Split(line, ' ')[3]->c_str(), '/' )[1]->c_str()) );
            d->F.push_back(OBJFace(vert, norms, textures));
        }
    }
}else { /* Error handling code! */ }
stream.close();
```

The above version takes waaay to long up to 1 minute for larger objs!

**So My Question: How would I parse the "Memory-mapped Version" in minimum amount of time! And load the same OBJData structure as in the slower version!**

Comment: Show us a small example input.

Comment: I will post some code for you to look at soon, which will hopefully explain more than my descriptions might

Comment: What you could do is to avoid copying and allocating strings. You could parse directly from mapped memory. It would be more complicated, but faster.

Comment: Do you need just basic functionality or do you need material definitions from the obj file too?

Comment: No I'm fine with just the vertex, normal, texture and face defenitions!

Comment: Hi,  sorry for the delay, had a PSU fail and will be able to get it done tonight or tomorrow:)

Answer (score -1):

If you're parsing lots of and/or large files or if you're parsing a file for the first time then you are most probably I/O bound and prefetching might help. For example, you might want to start a parallel thread that goes over the memory-mapped file in order to fetch it from disk. In C++11 (not tested):

```
std::thread prefetch ([data,size]() {
  volatile char sink = 0;  // Volatile should prevent the compiler from optimizing away.
  for (char* pt = data, end = data + size; pt < end; pt += 1024) sink = *pt;
});
// ... Your parser here ...
prefetch.join();
```

(Linux has the [MAP_POPULATE flag](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to prefetch the mapping).

Comment: "Using a pointer will be a bit faster than using an index"? Welcome back Mr. Powers. It's now 2013. You've been sleeping since 1974. We have real compilers now.

Comment: @Jerry: I've not been sleeping that long, but for the given code the index is indeed as efficient as the pointer (tested with GCC), thanks.

Comment: Surely. Your answer is definitely improved.